# If $||x|| < \sup\{||x_i||\}$ and $||x|| > \inf\{||x_i||\}$, then is $x \in \{x_i\}$?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

For any set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, is it true that if $$||x|| < \sup\{||x_i|| : x_i \in X\} \quad\text{ and } \quad ||x|| > \inf\{||x_i|| : x_i \in X\}$$ then $$x \in X?$$

Comment: Do you mean $\sup\{||x_i||\}$? How do you define inequality on $\mathbb R^d?$

Comment: @Anvit Thanks for the catch. I accidentally wrote the element $x$ itself rather than the vector norm $||x||$, but now that's fixed.

Comment: @sawghol What does it mean to compare a scalar $||x||$ with a $d$-dimensional vector $\sup\{x_i\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just see for $d=1$ this is not true. Say your subset is $\{1,3\}$. Then $x=2$ satisfies hypothesis but conclusion doesn't follow

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Let d=1, and X={1/n | n /in N} then 0=inf(X)<2/3